# I can't get li elements' index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my list..

```
<li class="haftalar"><a value="7" class="click" href="#" title="7. Hafta Maç Özetleri">7. Hafta</a></li>
<li class="haftalar"><a value="8" class="click" href="#" title="8. Hafta Maç Özetleri">8. Hafta</a></li>
```

I want to get index as clicked li element's and class equaled to "haftalar".

I'm using this code but I can't get my want.

```
$(".click").toggle(function(){
  index = $(this).index();
}
```

Comment: Pass the selected li into the index() method. Something like $("#your-list").index(selectedLi);

Comment: Have you put your click event on the a tag, it should be on the li. Could you provide us your javascript to ?

Comment: What do you want from the markup when you click the listitems `<li>`.`value?`, `href?`,`class?`,`title?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example -

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ptC7t/1/

```
$('.haftalar').click(function(){
    alert($('.haftalar').index($(this)));
})
```

Comment: Just a thoguht; because you are receiving a jQuery object in the click event already, you do not need to wrap this again. Instead you can just say $('.haftalar').index(this). cheers!

Comment: but my clicked element's not $(".haftalar"). My clicked element's need $(.click)..

Comment: the event will propogate to the childs, so this should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".click").click(function(){
  index = $(".click").index(this);
}
```